# Extracting the PGP keyid from the public key file

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, pgp

Is there a way via an CLI tool or some kind of API to extract the PGP key ID from the PGP public key block?

I found the hexa value of the key in the binary file, but I guess the position is based on the key kind/size.

Basically, I have the base64 formatted public key and I would like to retrieve the key ID from it, without importing it with GnuPG.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) on OpenPGP message format talks about how to calculate key ID from public key.

Excerpts from [section 12.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-12.2):

> For a V3 key, the eight-octet Key ID consists of the low 64 bits of the public modulus of the RSA key.

And for V4 keys:

> A V4 fingerprint is the 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the octet 0x99, followed by the two-octet packet length, followed by the entire Public-Key packet starting with the version field.  The Key ID is the low-order 64 bits of the fingerprint.

You can easily parse the last 64 bits from the base64 encoded public keys, which is the key ID for the corresponding public key.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on "easily parse the last 64 bits..."? I generated a pgp key (Got its MPI in base64 format. Is it what is meant by public key?), copy-n-pasted it to [here](https://conv.darkbyte.ru/), for example, and counted last 8 bytes in hex representation. Is that correct?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `gpg --dry-run` to prevent changes.

Following line will print the key id in its output (can be modified using the usual modifiers like `--with-colons` for further processing). `A4FF2279` is the key ID in here.

```
$ gpg --dry-run --import pubkey.asc
gpg: key A4FF2279: public key "[User ID not found]" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
```

Just tried it, the key did not get stored to my keychain, but the key ID was printed. But watch out with `--dry-run`, the man page has a warning:

> ```
>    --dry-run
>          Don't make any changes (this is not completely implemented).
> ```

A more in-depth discussion of multiple variants for human-readable, machine-readable and very technical output for different versions of GnuPG is found in the [Stack Overflow question *How to display gpg key details without importing it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22136029/695343). All of them will also present the key ID.

Comment: Would be nice, if you could update your answer mentioning the `--import --import-options show-only`, which seams to be the cleanest solution (regarding the *not completely implemented* problem), like you already did here: [How to display gpg key details without importing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22147722/1885518)

Comment: Instead of duplicating the whole answer I went for a hotlink.

Comment: I had to add --verbose to have it print the ID/email. (First I also had to create the .gpg directory in $HOME - not sure if that's a WSL/Ubuntu quirk or what.)

Comment: @Murmel: `gpg --import --import-options show only` doesn't work with GPG 1.416.

Answer (score 25):

From the gpg manual (gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.11):

> --show-keys

> This commands takes OpenPGP keys as input and prints information about  them in  the  same  way  the command --list-keys does for locally stored key.  In addition the list options show-unusable-uids,  show-unusable-subkeys,  show-notations  and  show-policy-urls  are  also enabled.  As usual for automated processing, this command should be combined with the option --with-colons.

For instance:

```
$ gpg --show-keys docker-ce.gpg
pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88
uid                      Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]
```

where `9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88` is the key id.

Comment: Earlier versions of GPG, e.g. 2.1.18 don't have `--show-keys`.

Comment: @pts For them its `--import-options show-only --import`.

Answer (score 5):

```
gpg --with-fingerprint GPG-KEY-filename-that-you-downloaded-from-internet
```

For example :

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
gpg --with-fingerprint GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
```

Comment: can you expand this answer with what the command argument does and the output from that key?

Comment: command missing

Comment: I.e.: If you like to validate a downloaded Oracle Java RPM package, you may check the package via `rpm -qip <RPM> | grep -i signature` and check the key via `gpg --with-fingerprint RPM-GPG-KEY-ORACLE`. You will find as output `Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sat 06 Oct 2018 03:29:42 PM WEST, Key ID 72f97b74ec551f03` and `pub  2048R/EC551F03 2010-07-01 Oracle OSS group (Open Source Software group) <build@oss.oracle.com>
      Key fingerprint = 4214 4123 FECF C55B 9086  313D 72F9 7B74 EC55 1F03`. As you can see, Key ID `72f9 7b74 ec55 1f03` fits to the fingerprint.

Comment: `gpg --with-fingerprint FILENAME` works with GPG 1.4.16, but it doesn't work with GPG 2.1.18.

Answer (score 3):

To get the key IDs (8 bytes, 16 hex digits), this is the command which worked for me in GPG 1.4.16, 2.1.18 and 2.2.19:

```
gpg --list-packets <key.asc | awk '$1=="keyid:"{print$2}'
```

To get some more information (in addition to the key ID):

```
gpg --list-packets <key.asc
```

To get even more information:

```
gpg --list-packets -vvv --debug 0x2 <key.asc
```

The command

```
gpg --dry-run --keyid-format long --import <key.asc
```

also works in all 3 versions, but in GPG 2.1.18 it prints the key ID of the main key only (and not the subkeys), and in 1.4.16 it prints both the main keys and the subkeys.

Commands in other answers (e.g. `gpg --show-keys`, `gpg --with-fingerprint`, `gpg --import --import-options show-only`) don't work in some of the 3 GPG versions above, thus they are not portable when targeting multiple versions of GPG.

Comment: gpg 1 _defaults_ to short keyid but you can specify (or configure in gpg.conf) `--keyid-format=long`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thank you for proposing `--keyid-format long`. I've added it to my answer. However. I strill don't recommend using `gpg --dry-run --import` because of inconsistencies in subkey key ID reporting among GPG versions. I've also added this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After the public key has been imported

```
pgp --import PublicKeyToImport.asc
```

run

```
pgp --list-userids
```

to determine the key or User ID to be used with `--encrypt`.

```
Alg  Type Size/Type Flags   Key ID     User ID
---- ---- --------- ------- ---------- -------
```

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a solution without importing the key. This answer doesn't answer the question.